# Network printer HP gives error filter failed

Tags: printing, hp

I am trying to use the university printer (it is an HP-Laser Jet-600-M602) to print my document. It worked well until yesterday, now it says "Filter Failed".

I tried to follow what is reccommended on [this](https://thenumberzero.blogspot.com/2014/02/how-to-fix-hp-printer-filter-failed.html) site, but I cannot access `localhost:631`: it requires credentials that apparently I do not have.

I have never installed HP proprietary drivers: Ubuntu did all by itself when I asked to search for network printers.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem following [this site](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/cups-issue%3B-error-with-network-printer-usr-lib-cups-backend-hp-failed-on-client-4175601187/)

I had to use the commands

```
lpstat -p
cupsenable Hewlett-Packard-HP-LaserJet-600-M602
```